# Controllers that are not Gamepads in LWJGL

Tags: java, controller, lwjgl

I'm having troubles with Gamepad Support.

```
    try // to create the Controllers
    {
        Controllers.create();
    }
    catch(Exception exep)
    {}

    int allControllers=0;
    allControllers=Controllers.getControllerCount(); //finding out how much
    //of it do we have
```

It says that I have 3 Controllers. 
But the Gamepad is the Controller number 0.
Because when I poll n1 or n2 Controller -- game just crashes.

Does anyone knows hot to automatically pick working gamepad from this list and evade the Crash?

Comment: I've been doing some tests, it appears like those 2 additional Controllers are Keyboard and Mouse. But it's not really helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like nobody else can do it. I've been working on it for good, and there is only one solution so far. Here it is:

```
        for(int co=0;co<allControllers;co++)
        {
            gamepad = Controllers.getController(co);
            GamePadName=gamepad.getName();
            if(GamePadName.charAt(0)!='H' && GamePadName.charAt(0)!='U')
                Keys=checkGamepad(Keys);
        }
```

There are two controllers that can't be polled. On some PC's they are called "HID something", on other they are called "USB Keybord", "USB Mouse". Maybe on other PC's they will be called in other way. So we are not polling these Controllers, and game is not crashing... seems to be a bad solution, but I see no better.